# What is the purpose of the addFingerPrint property in a page template definition?

Tags: magnolia

I'm adding a JavaScript file to my Magnolia [page template definition](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/Page+definition). For example:

```
jsFiles:
  index:
    link: path/to/resource.js
    addFingerPrint: true
```

What happens when I set `addFingerPrint` to `true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `addFingerPrint` to `true` "embeds a file content fingerprint in the resource URL".

> Embeds a file content fingerprint in the resource URL. The fingerprint consists of a timestamp in the yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS format, and the word "cache" both preceded by the the standard selector ("~" tilde).

Source: https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/Theme#Theme-JavaScriptfiles